# How to prevent an application from locking files while they're in use?

Tags: mysql, database, wordpress, macos, mamp

Currently, I am syncing a WordPress project database between myself and my team via Dropbox.  I notice that Dropbox never syncs the database after I make changes to it until after I have stop the servers in MAMP.  This is causing conflicts occasionally if more than one member of my team edits the same database entry on their local machine and then each person closes their respective MAMP servers at different times.

I'm assuming this is because MAMP is locking the database folder while it is in use.  Is there any way to prevent MAMP from locking this folder or to give Dropbox privileges that extend past MAMP's file locking?

I would greatly appreciate any help!

Comment: file locking is usually done because it needs to be e.g. because the files are in an intermediate state. Is there some kind of real centralized multiuser database you could be using instead?

Comment: Dont sync the files. Create synch scripts in MySQL and then synchronize the scripts to the database. This way you can also rollback if you need.

Answer (score 0):

File locks are there for a reason. Attempting to bypass the file locking mechanism just seems to be asking for a corrupted database.

Although not at all practical nor safe, your team members can copy the file from their dropbox directory a non-synced directory make changes and overwrite the database file in dropbox. But this opens the door to overwriting others work if the version copied isn't the most up to date version (obviously).

A practical and safe solution is to connect to 1 database server and team members will be able to safely make changes on the server (and obviously everyone will have access to the most up to date version).

Comment: I would definitely be doing that if my web host allowed for remote mySQL connections.  Do you know of any affordable (or free) database hosting services? Obviously Dropbox is not the best solution, but it's all we've got right now.

Comment: I'm sure you've looked of the option on the control panel to allow remote connections. Have you contacted your hosting provider to turn that feature on for your account?

Comment: I haven't. Their support site says it's turned off for security reasons. I suppose it's still worth asking them to see if they will turn it on for me!